# ForiGate 60D Error VPN id=96603 msg="SSLVPN tunnel connection failed (Error=-12)."

Tags: ssl, vpn, fortigate

i can login to vpn from web browser with same user name and password 
but when i try from fortigate clinet i am getting the error

```
Error   VPN id=96603 msg="SSLVPN tunnel connection failed (Error=-12)."
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Any information in server log files? Have you checked that the actual VPN is enabled on the server? Does the server have separate credentials for VPN access?

Comment: No log in server.. But VPN session was created

Comment: Means error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because in IE internet options we have to allow cookies

Comment: VPN sessions don't have any cookies, so I wonder how exactly would these things be related...